# Why SQL statement fails when INT use in SQL condition for column type is varchar and run without any error when numeric type colum added as condition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a SQL server table column which is defined as `varchar` and data stored in this column is `1,2,3`. I ran the following query and it failed (I am clear with the reason):

```
select * from <table> where <column1> in (1,2,3)
```

However, I have another column in the same table which is defined as `numeric`. If I add another condition using `numeric` column in to the above query, it works:

```
select * from <table> where <column1> in (1,2,3) and <column2> = 20
```

Can someone please explain the reason why SQL Server behaves like this?

Also, I have larger query which contains conditions defined as first query works on some databases on the same database server while other database on the same server fails (Sorry, I can not paste the query here).

I ran above queries SQL Server 2008 R2 server.

Following is the error message I got;

Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '36O5A' to data type int.

Where '36O5A' is the first alpha numeric value right after series of "numeric character" values in the varchar column.

Comment: is that your SQL because it has syntax error - you need 'select * from where X in (1,2,3)' - do you need to CONVERT or CAST you varchar data appropriate to your tests?

Comment: The reason is likely different execution plans. Compare the plans and you'll probably see a difference that affects the order of predicate evaluation.

Comment: "it failed" is not a good problem description. Please post the exact error message you get so that there is no chance of a misunderstanding here.

Comment: I have update with correct error description. Thanks.!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `column1` is a varchar you should **not** compare it to numbers. `1` is a number `'1'` is a character value.

By passing numbers, SQL Server tries to convert the values in `column1` to a number - which fails in your first example because the column contains values that cannot be (implicitly) converted to a number.

The second query filters out those invalid numbers and thus it works.

Use proper character values in the first query and it will be fine:

```
select * 
from the_table 
where column1 in ('1','2','3');
```

---

If the first query works in some environment and it doesn't in others, then apparently those where it works only contain  values that can be converted to a number.

Even if the `where` condition only "selects" valid number, the database still has to compare **all** values in the table to find those that match the condition.

Even with an index on the column you can't rely on the database to only process "valid" values.

---

#### Never, ever rely on implicit data type conversion.

You just learned that the hard way.

Comment: Do you have explanation reason for second question?

"I have larger query which contains conditions defined as first query works on some databases on the same database server while other database on the same server fails"

Comment: @javaGuy: apparently those server where it works do not contain values in the column that can't be converted to numbers. It's all about the evil implicit data type conversion

Comment: but the still column type is varchar and contains values as '1', '2', '3' and we querying those as (1,2,3). So, generally, it MUST fail all the servers.

Comment: @javaGuy: the query needs to compare the values of **all** rows to find those that contain `'1'` `'2'` or `'3'` - including those rows that have "invalid" values

Comment: I respectfully disagree. If the query plan at the time results in plan that happens to not require a comparison against rows that happen to not be numeric (i.e. if some rows are filtered beforehand), the error will not occur. I've seen this happen in Oracle (but not SQL Server)

Comment: But all other comments stand - never ever allow implicit casts

Comment: I can say that failing of query at some SQL server is due to order of execution, query execution plan.

Answer (score 3):

You already know why your query fails: somewhere in `column1` there is data that cannot be converted to an `INT`, and the `IN` will convert the column data first before comparing (due to SQL Server's slightly byzantine rules for data conversion).

But the thing is that the query is not *guaranteed* to fail unless the engine is going to read the rows with the erroneous data and attempt the conversion, and that may or may not happen. For example, in your second query, if there is an index on `column2` that allows the server to eliminate all non-matching rows before the conversions ever happen and the optimizer happens to use it, you won't get an error. Obviously, you can't rely on this; any change in the plan (parallelism, a trace flag, a new version of SQL Server or even a different data distribution) could change things. If this sounds scary, it's because it is. It's possible for an incorrect query that never should have worked to work anyway for years, only to one day fail because *something* changed. I've seen it happen.

For all intents and purposes, you should consider predicate evaluation nondeterministic unless a `CASE` is involved (where the order of evaluation is guaranteed; the clauses are executed in order and a `THEN` is only executed if the `WHEN` is true). In this case, the fix is easy: the constants of the `IN` clause should have been character literals. In more complicated cases, a `CASE` may be necessary to force evaluation (for example, to avoid a division by zero error). In short: it must always be possible to evaluate a `WHERE` condition over *all* rows, or else your query is not guaranteed to work, and worse, it's also not guaranteed to *not* work.